# add two Tables to JRDataSource and DynamicReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am trying to make a report for accounts list.

I have a list of Accounts (ex List accounts).

```
public class Account extends Model{
 private String  accountNumber;
 private String  accountType;
 private BigDecimal currentBalance;
 private String accountStatus;
 private BigDecimal creditLimit = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

These accounts has several types , such as Savings,Current,Credit card etc.

I am trying to generate the report with DynamicReport and ReportLayout.

I want to create separate tables for account types. As follows,

```
+------------------------+
|accountType = Savings   |
+------------------------+
|accountNumber           |
|currentBalance          |
|accountStatus           |
+------------------------+

+------------------------+
|accountType =Credit Card|
+------------------------+
|accountNumber           |
|currentBalance          |
|accountStatus           |
|creditLimit             |
+------------------------+
```

So is that possible?

I tried to find a solution. But I failed. Can anyone suppose a solution??

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>(accountMap.values());

JRDataSource ds = null;
DynamicReport dr = null;

ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource((Collection<?>) accounts);

ReportLayout layout = new ReportLayout();

dr = layout.buildReportLayout();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: I have edited my question.